# Can a JSON schema enforce a number array type property to have the elements in the ascending order?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Suppose if i have the schema for a property like

> Points": {
>           "type": "array",
>           "items": {
>               "type": "number",
>               "minimum": 0,
>               "maximum": 10
>           },
>          "minItems": 6,
>          "maxItems": 30 }

Can I enforce that all the numbers in the Points array from input JSON are in the ascending order through schema?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You could sort them yourself before or after, which ever makes sense in your workflow.

Comment: @Relequestual, Yes We can check whether the numbers are sorted but I wanted to know whether that is already possible through schema and reject if they are not.

Comment: No this is not currently possible.

Comment: Thanks @Relequestual

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not something that's currently possible.